# i wanted to take a id of label from repeater?

Tags: c#, asp.net, find, label

I have a Repeater binded with database data. I need to find out the `Product ID` binded to `Label` but am unable to fetch it.

Here is my Aspx page

```
 <asp:Repeater ID="rpProducts" runat="server" OnItemCommand ="add_click" >
                                    <ItemTemplate>
                                       <div style="visibility: hidden">
         <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("id")%>' ></asp:Label>

                                         </div>
                                        <div class="col-sm-4 prdcts">
                                            <h3>
                                                <%# Eval("productName")%></h3> 
                                            <div class="col-sm-12 prdctbox">
                                                <span class="AddToCrt">
                                                    <div title="Add to Cart">
                                                       <%-- <em class="fa fa-plus"></em>--%>
                                                        <asp:ImageButton ID="ImageButton1" runat="server" onclick="add_click" Height="22px" 
                                ImageUrl="~/static/uploads/images/1_1-128.png" Width="24px"/>
                                                    </div>
                                                </span>
                                                <div class="imgs">
                                                    <%# Eval("productDescription")%>
                                                </div>
                                                <%# Eval("listingHTML")%>
                                                <div class="row">
                                                    <a href="/en/product/detail.aspx?pId=<%# Eval("id")%>" class="sqare_easer">More</a>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </ItemTemplate>
                                </asp:Repeater>
```

my codding in c# is

```
//void rpProducts(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
        //{
        //    Label l = (Label)e.Item.FindControl("Label1");
        //    string s = l.Text;
        //}
        //protected void add_Click(object sender, RepeaterCommandEventArgs e)
        //{
        //    Label l = (Label)e.Item.FindControl("Label1");
        //    string s = l.Text;
        //}

        protected void ImageButton2_Click(object sender, ImageClickEventArgs e)
        {
            Label l = (Label)e.Item.FindControl("Label1");
            string s = l.Text;
        }

        protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
```

Is there any way to fetch the label value?

Answer (score 1):

You don't need the hidden label at all. You just need to change markup for your button a little bit.

```
<asp:ImageButton ID="ImageButton1" runat="server" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("id")%>' ... />
```

And in you codebehind you can reference the id like:

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  var button = (IButton)sender;
  // assuming id is Int32
  int id = int.Parse(button.CommandArgument);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `Label1` is inside ItemTemplate so correct way to fetch the control value is

```
 protected void ImageButton2_Click(object sender, ImageClickEventArgs e)
        {
           if(e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item|| e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem)
            {
            Label l = (Label)e.Item.FindControl("Label1");
            string s = l.Text;
             }
        }
```